# Fetch data from a website using LibreOffice Calc

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I'm searching for a way to fetch some data from a website using LibreOffice  Calc.

The website URL is: https://www.foresteu.com/termekeink//34653258430-abs-elzaro-kronospan-1543mm-k105-fp-raw-endgrain-oak

Treid to fetch the H3 Title already `=FILTERXML(WEBSERVICE("https://www.foresteu.com/termekeink//34653258430-abs-elzaro-kronospan-1543mm-k105-fp-raw-endgrain-oak"),"//h3")` but i get `#VALUE!`as result.

I would love to get h3 title and product properties: Cikkszám: 34653258430 Anyag: MŰANYAG Szélesség: 43 Szín: FAUTÁNZAT Vastagság: 1,5 separated into cells like: `Cikkszám: 34653258430` `Anyag: MŰANYAG` `Szélesség: 43` `Szín: FAUTÁNZAT` `Vastagság: 1,5`

I am using latest version of LibreOffice Calc. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FILTERXML` is only for XML not HTML.
Even `xpath=//h3` won't work.

But you can try the following, use the menu item :

- Insert
- Link to external data
- Type in or paste the URL of the Web page hit ENTER, wait a few seconds, set the parameters in the appeared small panel, then choose a tab from the resulting table, Click on OK.

> If the Web table is HTML based, the data will appeared. But when the table was made with other technology, the data link will not work.